# How to read a table to use for Node locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Let us assume that we have a two column table in a .txt file:

[image: first]

As we see the table has a header x y that we skip.
The next row is to be the location of Node A at (0, 0). Similarly, the next row will be the location of Node B at (1,1). I am looking for a tikz file in which I can directly read the (0,0) and (1,1) from the .txt table and assign them to the locations of Nodes A and B. Below is a sample code that I could not read the table:

```
\begin{filecontents}{testOne.txt}
    x   y
    0   0
    1   1
\end{filecontents}


  \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node  at (0,0) (A){}; 
 \filldraw (A) circle (1pt);
 \node [anchor= west] at (A){$A$};

 \node  at (1,1) (B){}; 
 \filldraw (B) circle (1pt);
 \node [anchor= west] at (B){$B$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

And the desired result is:
[image: second]

Do you know how to read the table and use it for the locations of my nodes?

Answer (score 6):

For this particular table header with `x` in the first column using package `listofitems`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{testOne.txt}
    x   y
    0   0
    1   1
\end{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listofitems} % split space separated items
% \fileopenr{<file stream>}{<file name>}, opens file for reading
\newcommand\fileopenr[2]{%
  \newread#1%
  \immediate\openin#1=#2%
}
% \readtolist{<file stream>}{\list}
%   reads a line from file stream and splits at ' ' into \list[1], \list[2], ...
\newcommand\readtolist[2]{%
  \begingroup%
    \immediate\read#1 to \inputline%
    \ifeof#1
      \immediate\closein#1%
    \else%
      \setsepchar{ }%
      \greadlist*#2\inputline%
      \def\x{x}\edef\first{#2[1]}%
      \ifx\first\x% skip table header
        \readtolist{#1}{#2}%
      \fi%  
    \fi%
  \endgroup%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\fileopenr{\infile}{testOne.txt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \readtolist{\infile}{\table}
  \node  at (\table[1],\table[2]) (A){}; 
  \filldraw (A) circle (1pt);
  \node [anchor= west] at (A){$A$};

  \readtolist{\infile}{\table}
  \node  at (\table[1],\table[2]) (B){}; 
  \filldraw (B) circle (1pt);
  \node [anchor= west] at (B){$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expl3 expert, I suggest

- read the first line (no processing)
- one line at a time,
  -separate x and y with space in seq
  -create a node named P1 for the first point, P2...
  (edit2: I forgot to close the file)

  ```
   \begin{filecontents*}{testOne.txt}
       x   y
       0   0 
       1   1
   \end{filecontents*}
   \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
   %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641621/how-to-read-a-table-to-use-for-node-locations

   \usepackage{tikz}
   \tikzset{
       mynode/.style={
       fill=black,
       circle,
       inner sep=0pt,
       outer sep=0pt,
       minimum width=1mm}
       }
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \ior_new:N \g_yourmodule_ior
   \seq_new:N \l__yourmodule_coordonnees_seq
   \int_new:N \l__yourmodule_numPoint_int% for P1, P2
   \NewDocumentCommand \myPoints { m }
   {       % #1--> name of file
       \ior_open:Nn \g_yourmodule_ior { #1 }
       \ior_get:NN \g_yourmodule_ior \l_tmpa_tl%<-- the first line
       \int_set:Nn \l__yourmodule_numPoint_int { 0 }
       \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_yourmodule_ior
           {%  one line at a time 
           \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__yourmodule_coordonnees_seq { } { ##1 }% separate x and y by the space
           \int_incr:N \l__yourmodule_numPoint_int
           \node[mynode] (P \int_eval:n {\l__yourmodule_numPoint_int}) at (\seq_item:Nn \l__yourmodule_coordonnees_seq { 1 },\seq_item:Nn \l__yourmodule_coordonnees_seq { 2 }){};
           }
       \ior_close:N \g_yourmodule_ior%<-- 
   }
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \myPoints {testOne.txt}
       \node[right] at(P1){$A$};
       \node[right] at(P2){$B$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `PGFPlots` and use its table parsing mechanism:

```
\begin{filecontents}{testOne.txt}
    x   y
    0   0
    1   1
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotstableread{testOne.txt}\coordinatetable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\coordinatetable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coordinatecount{\pgfplotsretval - 1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\coordinatecount}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{x}\of{\coordinatetable}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tempx{\pgfplotsretval}
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{y}\of{\coordinatetable}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tempy{\pgfplotsretval}
        \coordinate (n#1) at (\tempx,\tempy); 
        \filldraw (n#1) circle (1pt);
        \node[anchor=west] at (n#1) {\symbol{\numexpr65+#1}};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]